# jQuery plugin for table with removable columns

Tags: jquery-plugins

I would like to display a table with many columns. All columns cannot fit into one screen, so I want let user to decide which columns to see and which not (I will have some default, of course).

I found the SlickGrid jQuery plugin which does have the required functionality. [Demo here.](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) But, it has also many other things that I'm not interested in.

I wonder if there are other jQuery plugins that has this functionality. Please share if you know some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid - Demo at http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html - Has a feature for showing/hiding columns but again offers a lot of other features you might not be interested in but most can be turned off.